# How to read with Spark constantly updating HDFS directory and split output to multiple HDFS files based on String (row)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, spark-streaming

Elaborated scenario -> HDFS directory which is "fed" with new log data of multiple types of bank accounts activity.
Each row represents a random activity type, and each row (String) contains the text "ActivityType=`<TheTypeHere>`".

In Spark-Scala, what's the best approach to read the input file/s in the HDFS directory and output multiple HDFS files, where each ActivityType is written to its own new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted first answer to the statement:

> The location of the "key" string is random within the parent String,
>   the only thing that is guaranteed is that it contains that sub-string,
>   in this case "ActivityType" followed by some val.

The question is really about this. Here goes:

```
// SO Question
val rdd = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/activitySO.txt")  
val rdd2 = rdd.map(x => (x.slice (x.indexOfSlice("ActivityType=<")+14, x.indexOfSlice(">", (x.indexOfSlice("ActivityType=<")+14))), x))
val df = rdd2.toDF("K", "V")
df.write.partitionBy("K").text("SO_QUESTION2")
```

Input is:

```
ActivityType=<ACT_001>,34,56,67,89,90
3,4,4,ActivityType=<ACT_002>,A,1,2
ABC,ActivityType=<ACT_0033>
DEF,ActivityType=<ACT_0033>
```

Output is 3 files whereby the key is e.g. not ActivityType=, but rather ACT_001, etc. The key data is not stripped, it is still there in the String. You can modify that if you want as well as output location and format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultipleOutputFormat for this.Convert rdd into key value pairs such that ActivityType is the key.Spark will create different files for different keys.You can decide based on the key where to place the files and what their names will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using RDDs whereby I assume you have variable length files and then converting to DFs:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/activity.txt")
val rdd2 = rdd.map(_.split(","))
          .keyBy(_(0))
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(x => (x._1, x._2.mkString(",")))
val df = rdd3.toDF("K", "V")  
//df.show(false)

df.write.partitionBy("K").text("SO_QUESTION")
```

Input is:

```
ActivityType=<ACT_001>,34,56,67,89,90
ActivityType=<ACT_002>,A,1,2
ActivityType=<ACT_003>,ABC
```

I get then as output 3 files, in this case 1 for each record. A bit hard to show as did it in Databricks.

You can adjust your output format and location, etc. partitionBy is the key here.

Comment: Thanks, I see you are assuming the "key" sub-string will always be in the same position, however this isn't the case for me.  The location of the "key" string is random within the parent String, the only thing that is guaranteed is that it contains that sub-string, in this case "ActivityType" followed by some val.

Comment: Ok, that was not clear. Sort of implies pre-processing. Need to think on that.